# Add a directory to a Github repository without submoduling

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I pulled someone's Github repository. I added a directory within a directory and push it back up to Github.

When I push to Github, the directory appears as a green folder, a submodule. I want this new directory to simply appear as a folder. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How exactly did you add the new dir?  git add?

Comment: Tried to do it two ways. First `cp -r source_path destination_path` and then visually dragging and dropping using Mac Finder

Comment: You have to git add dest_path ; otherwise git treats it as untracked and it won't get committed etc.

Comment: @seand that had no effect. It's being committed, just as a submodule which can't be interacted with unless the repo is pulled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the folder you're adding is itself a git repo. Check it - does it contain a ".git" sub-folder? If so, removing the ".git" folder from the copy will allow you to perform a standard "git add", "git commit" in the root repo you're adding this folder into.

Comment: +1 Thanks @Ryan! For future users, I had to commit without the directory and then re-add it without the .git sub-folder and commit again.